# Extract positive and negative vales from Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have 3D matrix like this

```
1   5648.00278672228    -46.43159546036
1   5650.38906894239    68.81787768047
1   5649.13081105839    -4867.55961979647
1   5650.53055771227    4868.95936645035
1   5647.95215053492    4866.38095927300
1   5650.21656586142    -2328.64537459950
1   5651.76371933598    7870.19252807406
1   5649.87288540620    -1168.30169414428
```

and I want to extract positive and negative values of 3rd column into two seperate 2D matrices (POS and NEG) where 1st column contains the index of the row from the above matrix, and second column contains the value.

The result should look like

```
POS = 
2   68.81787768047
4   4868.95936645035
5   4866.38095927300
7   7870.19252807406
```

and

```
NEG =  
1   -46.43159546036
3   -4867.55961979647
6   -2328.64537459950
8   -1168.30169414428
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the `find` function and logical indexing

```
POS = [find(A(:,3)>0) A(A(:,3)>0,3)]
NEG = [find(A(:,3)<=0) A(A(:,3)<=0,3)]
```

For your input matrix being A

```
A = [1   5648.00278672228    -46.43159546036
    1   5650.38906894239    68.81787768047
    1   5649.13081105839    -4867.55961979647
    1   5650.53055771227    4868.95936645035
    1   5647.95215053492    4866.38095927300
    1   5650.21656586142    -2328.64537459950
    1   5651.76371933598    7870.19252807406
    1   5649.87288540620    -1168.30169414428]
```

the results will be (with `format shortG`)

```
POS =

        2       68.818
        4         4869
        5       4866.4
        7       7870.2


NEG =

        1      -46.432
        3      -4867.6
        6      -2328.6
        8      -1168.3
```

*the second find was removed thanks to @Dennis Jaheruddin and Khurram Majeed' comments.*

Comment: The second find in each line can be left out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, FYI,I am using Matlab 2013a and its is suggesting me that 
`To speed up and simplify the program, replace the call to find with logical array indexing.` and when I click automatic fix, it removes the `find` for the second column

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternate way to do it

```
p = find(A(:,3)>0);
n = find(A(:,3)<0);

POS = [p A(p,3)]
NEG = [n A(n,3)]
```

Note that this does not include zero entries. If you want them in the first vector for example use `>=` instead of `>`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is yet another way:

```
B = [(1:size(A,1)).' A(:,3)];
inds = B(:,2)>0;
POS = B( inds,:);
NEG = B(~inds,:);
```

This is faster than Magla's `find` solution:

```
tic
for ii = 1:1e5
    B = [(1:size(A,1)).' A(:,3)];
    inds = B(:,2)>0;
    POS = B( inds,:);
    NEG = B(~inds,:);
end
toc

tic
for ii = 1:1e5
    POS = [find(A(:,3)>0) A(A(:,3)>0,3)];
    NEG = [find(A(:,3)<=0) A(A(:,3)<=0,3)];
end
toc
```

Results on my crappy machine:

```
Elapsed time is 1.290744 seconds. % my new solution
Elapsed time is 2.004015 seconds. % Magla's solution w/ find()
```

This difference is partly due to skipping `find`, negating the logical indices instead of comparing again to `<= 0`, and re-using the indices instead of re-computing them.

Even compared to a more optimal version of Magla's solution:

```
tic
for ii = 1:1e5
    inds = A(:,3)>0;
    POS = [find( inds) A( inds,3)];
    NEG = [find(~inds) A(~inds,3)];
end
toc
```

we find

```
Elapsed time is 1.290744 seconds. % my new solution
Elapsed time is 1.476138 seconds. % Magla's solution w/ find()
```